# Javascript: change element value by input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, element

I want to change THISVALUE using a textbox and submit button, which then refreshes the data on the page:

```
<form id="newssearch" action="#">
  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="155" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Search" onclick="showElements();" />
</form>

<div class="sm" data-type="static" data-symbol="THISVALUE" data-size="medium" data-logscale="on" data-chart-type="ca" data-timeframe="1y"></div>

<div class="sm" data-type="news" data-symbol="THISVALUE"></div>
```

Also: you press the button and it refreshes the page with the new data-symbol value. That value stays for the next visit to the page or until  another search is performed.

Perhaps it would be better to do this in php?

Comment: Can you attach the form?

Comment: Make sure you provide some code for the community to be able to help you out.

Comment: Can you paste the code instead of attaching a pic.

Comment: ^^^ To all the comments above:  when you see an new user write "Here's the form:" and you see no form, try editing the question, chances are OP did not know how to use code blocks and therefor no code was visible...

Comment: Will definitely keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Answer (score 1):

First off - `data-symbol` is not an element. It is an attribute and to be more specific - a `data` attribute.

Learn more about data attributes here: [Using `data` attributes | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

---

I assume you want the data submitted in the form to get into the `data-symbol` attribute.

Checkout the working code snippet below:

```js
function showElements(){

  // just copy over the search text into the data attribute
  document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[0].dataset.symbol = document.getElementById('search').value;

}
```

```html
<div class="blah" data-type="cur" data-symbol="THISVALUE"></div>


<form id="newssearch" action="#">

  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="155" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Search" onclick="showElements();" /> <!-- no need to pass any arguments to this function, we can get data using element ID -->

</form>
```

---

Check the result using Developer Tools (I have used Chrome here):

[image]

Comment: sorry a bit irrelevant to the question being asked here. How do you add run code snippet to your answer? I checked the help page but couldn't find anything

Comment: this is off topic, but Is that a stackoverflow version of jsfiddle?

Comment: Google is your friend :) You can always Google it if you don't find it in help section. Here you go: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith ^

Comment: @user6439245 FYI ^

Comment: @RahulDesai Thanks :)

Comment: @RahulDesai thanks for the sarcasm, however it is hard to google something when you do not know what you are googling for...

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I agree with you :)

Comment: Thanks all. I didn't explain it properly... I want to change THISVALUE using button

<form id="newssearch" action="#">

  <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="155" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Search" onclick="showElements();" /> <!-- no need to pass any arguments to this function, we can get data using element ID -->

</form>

<div class="sm" data-type="static" data-symbol="THISVALUE" data-size="medium" data-logscale="on" data-chart-type="ca" data-timeframe="1y"></div>


<div class="sm" data-type="news" data-symbol="THISVALUE"></div>

Comment: Also....You press the button and it refreshes the page with the new data-symbol value. That value stays for the next visit to the page or another search is performed.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to do this in php?

Comment: Sorry Rahul, it doesn't work. Can you or anyone help?

Comment: What about doing it this way??: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765716/php-form-handler

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `setAttribute()` function

```
function showElements(){

  document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[0].setAttribute("data-symbol",document.getElementById('search').value);

}
```